# Apache: how to create subdomain on name-based virtualhost?

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

i have name-based hosting, lets name it `my.address.com` - my friend have 'white' ip -`address.com` and gave me virtual machine than i can access via ssh, also, he made some magic with ports and now after install apache i could access /var/www on the `my.address.com`. 
So, the question is how can i make subdomain like `test.my.address.com`? There are should be some magick with [Apache's Listen Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#listen), but i cant figure it finally.
Also, i know how to create local-available sites with apache, but it is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend has to create another name based virtual host in the apache config files to make `test.my.address.com` SSH access to `/var/www` I assume is only the web root, not the apache folder.

If you have SSH access to / server root folder and have SU privileges you can create your own sub subdomain virtual host.

Comment: yes, i have root access to /  **on the virtual machine**, is it what i need? so, what should i do?

Comment: Use this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts